# Issues with Mongoose findById command

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a nodejs express router with the following route:

```
router.get("/book/:id", function(req, res){

    Book.findById(req.params.id).then(function(book){
        if (book) {
            res.json(book);
        } else {
            res.send("Book Not found");
        }
    }).catch(function(err){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
            throw err;
        }
    })
})
```

when i test the route using postman i always get this error:

```
  { [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5e441654a8b2e25bfa3d4507" at path "_id" for model "Book"]
  stringValue: '"5e441654a8b2e25bfa3d4507"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '5e441654a8b2e25bfa3d4507',
  path: '_id',
  reason: [TypeError: hex is not a function],
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5e441654a8b2e25bfa3d4507" at path "_id" for model "Book"',
  name: 'CastError',
  model: Model { Book } }
```

It seems like the findById command is requesting a mongoose objectId type not a string
i tried online solution (from stack and other communities) and i found something similar to:

```
ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId
ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId 
ObjectId = mongoose.mongo.ObjectId
```

Then 
the solution suggests to do something like:

```
id = new ObjectId(req.params.id)
Book.findById(id)
```

Still not working with a `hex is not a function` error

Does anyone encountered this error and manage to fix it ?
Note that I'm using:

```
mongodb cloud hosting, version 4
mongoose 5.8.11
nodejs 4.2.6
```

and here is my book model if it helps:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({

       title: {
           type: String,
           require: true
       },
       author: {
            type: String,
            require: true
       },
       numberPages: {
            type: Number,
            require: false
       },
       publisher: {
           type: String,
           require: false
       }

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', schema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the node driver is causing the issue (found out i'm using an old node version of 4.6), i upgraded my nodejs version and now it's working, Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
...
var myId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)
Book.findById(myId).then(function(book) {
...
```

It should work.

Comment: Tried it before, it throws an error that says `TypeError: hex is not a function`

Comment: Can you try: `console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(myId))` and see if you are getting `true`?

Comment: the issue is with the casting itself `var myId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)` it's what's throwing the `hex is not a function` error so it will fail before reaching the console.log statement

Comment: `TypeError: hex is not a function
    at Function.from (native)
    at Function.from (native)
    at Object.toBuffer (/home/jihedzouari/node-library-micro/books/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/utils.js:20:22)
    at new ObjectID (/home/jihedzouari/node-library-micro/books/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:63:31)
    at /home/jihedzouari/node-library-micro/books/app/api.js:46:20
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/jihedzouari/node-library-`

Comment: Btw if i add `console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))` it returns true which is weird.

Comment: Oh. Then that is weird. Just out of curiosity, can you please tell me what is mongo server version?

Comment: As mentioned, 4.2.3 (i have a feeling it's the main cause of my issue)

Comment: Can you install simple `npm install mongodb` driver and then try to convert it to hex by using `var mongodb = require(‘mongodb’); var myId = mongodb.ObjectId(id)`?

Comment: same error `GET /book/5e441654a8b2e25bfa3d4507 500 29.705 ms - 1961
TypeError: hex is not a function
    at Function.from (native)
    at Function.from (native)
    at Object.toBuffer (/home/jihedzouari/node-library-micro/books/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/utils.js:20:22)
    at new ObjectID (/home/jihedzouari/node-library-micro/books/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:63:31)
    at /home/jihedzouari/node-library-micro/books/app/api.js:50:20
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/jihedzouari/node-library-.........`

Answer (score 0):

You must be passing that id in params directly string, like this `id="5e441654a8b2e25bfa3d4507"`. Try to pass `id=5e441654a8b2e25bfa3d4507` without the quotes.

Comment: i'm not using any quotes in my postman request `localhost:4545/book/5e441654a8b2e25bfa3d4507`

Comment: I passed this localhost:3111/book/"5e441654a8b2e25bfa3d4507"... this throwing me the same error as you have. Then I pass this localhost:3111/book/5e441654a8b2e25bfa3d4507 that work

Comment: I This it might be an issue with the versions of mongodb and mongoose.

Comment: can you show me your pamas in backend. By console.log(req.params)

Comment: `{ id: '5e441654a8b2e25bfa3d4507' }`

Comment: But in your error stringValue is this. stringValue: '"5e441654a8b2e25bfa3d4507"',

Comment: Any idea on what to do ?