# Can't update data to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i'm doing basic CRUD. All are okay except Update. Cannot update the data to the database.

***My get and Post method for update operation***

```
router.get('/admin_user/edit/:id',function(req,res){
  User.findOne({_id:req.params.id},function(err,users){
      res.render('admin_content/edit_user',{'users':users});
  });
});

router.post('/admin_user/edit/:id',function(req,res){
  // update Data
  var userUpdate={
    username: req.body.username,
    name: req.body.name,
    roles: req.body.roles
  };
  var message='Data has been not updated';
  User.updateOne({_id:req.params.id},userUpdate,function(err,numrows){
      if(!err){
          res.redirect('/admin_user');
      }
  });
});
```

**EJS form**

```
 <form method="post" action="/admin_user/edit/:id" >
                                <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1">Full name</label><input class="form-control py-4" type="name" name="name" placeholder=<%= users.name %> /></div>
                                <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1" >Email</label><input class="form-control py-4"  type="username"  name="username" placeholder=<%= users.username %> /></div>
                                <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1" >Select Roles</label>
                                    <select name="roles" id="roles">
                                        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                        <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
                                        <option value="creator">Creator</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group mt-4 mb-0"><input type="submit" value="Submit" a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="/admin_user"></div>           
                            </form>
```

Comment: what kind of error you're getting here? Have you tried to console that?

Comment: A very common error in this situation is that `req.params.id` is a string, and the `_id` field contains an ObjectId, so the update filter doesn't match any documents, and nothing gets updated.

Comment: yeap I tried console which will display "not update" if update not perform and it did.

Comment: And my `_id` looks like this "_id" : ObjectId("5ea1ccc95b645f30582aac11"), @joe

Comment: take a look at the answers for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191669/issues-with-mongoose-findbyid-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved i'm using this in ejs

```
<form method="post" action="/admin_user/edit/<%= users._id %>" >
```